# Letsencrypt, es necesario el webroot path?

Tags: nginx, letsencrypt

Estoy configurando un servidor con Nginx y letsencrypt pero tengo dudas de si es obligatorio rellenar este campo.

```
letsencrypt certonly -a webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/html -d example.com
```

Tengo una aplicación node en /home/pruebas/index.js, es este mi webroot?

Saludos y gracias

Answer (score 1):

El home es el directorio donde esta tu .htacces y si si es necesario , pues letsencrypt hace pruebas ACME contra tu servidor para verificar que seas el dueño del servidor

Comment: la primera pregunta me ha quedado claro, pero.. y la segunda? no tengo htaccess